# I'm developing a DocuSign web application with embedded signing. I get error on createEnvelope on my deployed test site

Tags: asp.net-core, docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign's .net SDK eSign 5.8.0. I have my application working from Visual Studio 2022. Everything is working fine with embedded signing running locally with my DocuSign development account. I deployed the web application to a test server that is publicly visible. I added the test server url to the application's list of redirect urls. I'm using JWT authentication, from my log files my authentication is good. I'm creating an envelope from a template. My exception is DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: Error calling CreateEnvelope

```
Server Error

 404 - File or directory not found.
 The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its 
name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in my code. My DocuSign baseUri was just demo.docusign.net, instead of demo.docusign.net/restapi